# copy table (create table like) - not keeping auto incrementing primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm new to postgres (on 9.5) and I can't find this in the docs anywhere.

Basically create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
        id serial primary key, 
        field1 CHARACTER VARYING(50)
        );
```

Then copy it:

```
create table test_copy (like test);
```

The table test has these columns:

```
COLUMN_NAME id  field1
DATA_TYPE   4   12
TYPE_NAME   serial  varchar
COLUMN_SIZE 10  50
IS_NULLABLE NO  YES
IS_AUTOINCREMENT     YES    NO
```

But test_copy has these:

```
COLUMN_NAME id  field1
DATA_TYPE   4   12
TYPE_NAME   int4    varchar
COLUMN_SIZE 10  50
IS_NULLABLE NO  YES
IS_AUTOINCREMENT     NO NO
```

Why am I losing serial and autoincrement?  How can I make a copy of a table that preserves these?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `serial` isn't really a datatype. It gets "expanded" to an integer + a sequence + a default value.

[See the manual for details](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

To get the default definition you need to use `create table test_copy (like test INCLUDING DEFAULTS)`.

However,  that will then use the **same** sequence as the original table.

You can see the difference when you display the table definition in `psql`:

```
psql (9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> CREATE TABLE test (
postgres(>         id serial primary key,
postgres(>         field1 CHARACTER VARYING(50)
postgres(>         );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> create table test_copy_no_defaults (like test);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> create table test_copy (like test including defaults);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> \d test
                                Table "public.test"
 Column |         Type          |                     Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer               | not null default nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass)
 field1 | character varying(50) |
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

postgres=> \d test_copy
                             Table "public.test_copy"
 Column |         Type          |                     Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer               | not null default nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass)
 field1 | character varying(50) |

postgres=> \d test_copy_no_defaults
    Table "public.test_copy_no_defaults"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 id     | integer               | not null
 field1 | character varying(50) |
```

Comment: Thanks!  To clarify, what do you mean about the "same sequence"?  Is that something I Don't want?

Comment: Correct, that is something you don't want. An insert in the copied table will increment the id of the next insert in the original table (and vice versa). I'm googling around 4 years later to find the best solution to also copy the sequence with the table.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

`create table test_inh () inherits (test);`

and then

`alter table test_inh no inherit test;`

should leave same sequence default value for you

Comment: It seems like that works.  What's the alter statement for?

Comment: when you inherit table it not only copies structure it "keeps reference". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html so if you only want to replicate structure, you create inheritate table and gthen uninherit it